# references for families of conditionaly negative definite matrices 

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, co.combinatorics, matrices

We say that a matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a conditionaly negative definite matrix if it is hermitian and if for all complex numbers $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ such that $c_1+\cdots +c_n=0$ we have
$$
\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}c_j\overline{c_k}a_{jk}\leq 0.
$$

I'm interested by non-trivial families $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of concrete matrices where each $A_n$ is a conditionaly negative definite matrix of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that all diagonal entries are null (important: the dimension of $A_n$ grows with $n$).

Has anyone seen this sort of thing in the literature?

I'm also interested by the related examples of non-trivial infinite conditionaly negative definite matrices (the definition of these is similar) such that all diagonal entries are null.

Comment: You question introduces a family of matrices, but then doesn't ask anything about _the family_.  So I don't really understand if you are asking just about "conditionally negative definite matrices with zero diagonal entries", or something else...?

Comment: I'm interested by complicated or interesting examples of conditionally negative definite matrices with zero diagonal entries.

Comment: Also, looking in Bekka, de la Harpe and Valette's book on Kazhdan's property (T), appendix C, then "conditionally negative type" is those _real_ matrices which satisfy your condition (for _real_ numbers $(c_i)$) with already the condition that $a_{jj}=0$ for all $j$.  Such things always arise as $a_{ij} = \|x_i-x_j\|^2$ where $(x_i)$ is a sequence in a real Hilbert space.

So if you question really about the fact you wish to use _complex_ numbers?

Comment: You can read Berg "Harmonic analysis on Semigroups" for some information of the useful definition of my post (page 67, with complex numbers).

Comment: Yep, that's a good reference!  But doesn't Proposition 3.2 in that book basically answer your question-- it gives a Hilbert space representation (a bit more complicated than my comment before).  That would surely give you lots of non-trivial examples...?

Comment: My vague recollection is that you get examples via Schoenberg's theorem, which has then been used in e.g. Haagerup's paper
<i>An example of a non-nuclear C*-algebra, which has the metric approximation property</i>, Inventiones Math. 50, 279-293 (1979). (Certain groups equipped with word metric give rise to cnd kernels via Schoenberg's theorem, but off the top of my head I am unsure of exactly which ones.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at: [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44777/how-to-characterize-real-square-matrices-a-such-that-vav-0-for-all-real-vec/44789#44789)---there you will find several references, from which you can gather a list of nontrivial cnd matrices (especially, the nontrivial ones that arise from cnd kernels, which are related to Hilbert space embeddable (isometrically) metrics).